# Editing front page in after logic

Tags: php, html, email, mail-server, webmail

I am using [after logic](http://www.afterlogic.com/webmail-client) as webmail client. I was trying to edit the front page, I have succesfully deployed it on my local server, I went to

```
/var/www/html/webmail/templates/views/Mail/
```

to edit the front page, what happening is very strange that even if I try to delete all code from the file , the web mail client still works fine, so could be that I am not in the right directory or the webmail is using some kind of caching.

Question :

How can I edit the front page of afterlogic.

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do but you can create your own login page and use your created custom login form post to index.php. They have documentation on that. http://www.afterlogic.org/docs/webmail-lite/integration-and-development/sending-login-credentials-via-post . That's what I did for my project and works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Upon making changes in a template, you need to purge data/cache/ directory content to apply the changes.